# Count all set bit sum upto the Nth number

Tags: algorithm, sum, bit-manipulation, bit

can anyone help me to crack any formula or code rather than O(n) to count the sum of number of set bits in upto Nth

```
N    Bit
```

```
Ex: 1 -> 1 
    2 -> 1 + 1 (this 1 is previous one as we are summing those)
    3 -> 4
    4 -> 5
    5 -> 7
    |    
    |
    Nth term formula???
```

I tried to crack the pattern like:

```
for first bit  2^0: 1 and 0 makes pattern of 01010101---------Nth
for second bit 2^1: 1 and 0 makes pattern of 00110011---------Nth
for third bit  2^2: 1 and 0 makes pattern of 00001111---------Nth
```

Comment: Is _"upto the Nth number"_ meant to be upto the Nth bit? Something like `sum = x & ((1u << N) - 1)` (with a check so that `N` isn't too big)?

Comment: no Nth bit its Nth number like 
1 has 1 bit set                              = 1
2 has 1 bit set and sum of 1 also = 2
3 has 2 bit set and previous sum = 2 + 2 = 4
upto Nth

Comment: Can't we do this for each bit? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-numbers-up-to-n-having-kth-bit-set

Comment: This has very little to do with programming.

Comment: This sequence [is on the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000788), including [efficient implementation](https://oeis.org/A000788/a000788.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look for dependencies. Results for `0001111**` (`k` ones) patterns are `k*2^(k-1)`, so result for patterns containing the onle one "1" (`2^k`) is `1 + k*2^(k-1)`. So we can separate the most significant one bit (MSB), get count for numbers upto corresponding power of two, then add both count for right tail value and that right tail value itself (because of MSB). Python code:

```
def cnt_ones(n):
    if n==0: return 0
    leftbit = 1
    bitnum = 0
    cnt = 0

    while leftbit*2 <= n:  #find power of two for MSB
        leftbit <<= 1
        bitnum += 1

    while leftbit:  #now check bits from left to right
        if n & leftbit:
            cnt += 1    +        (leftbit//2) * bitnum +   (n & (leftbit - 1))
                # MSB bit itself   
                               #count for numbers before this power of two
                                                           # tail value      
        leftbit >>= 1
        bitnum -= 1
    return cnt

0 0
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 5
5 7
6 9                 
7 12     #3*2^2
8 13     #1+3*2^2
9 15
10 17
11 20
12 22
13 25
14 28   # 1 + 3*2^2 + (14-8) + count(14-8) 
15 32
16 33
17 35
18 37
...
30 75
31 80
32 81
33 83
```

Addition:

Why numbers upto `k` ones give `k*2^(k-1)` bits:

Consider k-bits values from 0000 to 1111. There are 2^k of them. Every bit is "0" in the half  of values, and is "1", so we can count `2^(k-1)` ones for every bit number, and multiply by `k` for all `k` bits.

Why check bits from left to right?

If we have binary value `1110`, we can count ones for values in range  `0000...1000` as above, then add count of ones in range `1001..1110`. The last range contains `110b=6dec` values, so we have to account for 6 one bits at the left, and count ones in `001..110` range and so on.

Comment: thanks, but can you please explain it, like why there is a need to find the power of two for MSB
and then checking bits from left to right?

In short please explain your comments why doing that thing only?

thanks you in advance

Comment: I added some explanation